# How do I use theme('links') with nested arrays?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I want to render the following output:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='url1'>link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='url2'>link 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='url3'>sub-link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='url4'>link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I was expecting this to be pretty straightforward:

```
$list = array(
  'item1' => array('title' => 'link 1', 'href' => 'url1'),
  'item2' => array(
    'title' => 'link 2', 'href' => 'url2',
    array(
      'item3' => array('title' => 'sub-link 3', 'href' => 'url3'),
    ),
  ),
  'item4' => array('title' => 'link 4', 'href' => 'url4' ),
);

$output = theme('links', array('links' => $list));
```

This outputs the following however, ignoring `item3`:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='url1'>link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='url2'>link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='url4'>link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can't do that with default function theme links. If you want can override function theme_links in your theme and process your logic. But i think better you define new function theme for that.

Comment: Hi @John, could you provide a code snippet to get me started?

Comment: Function theme_item_list() was done it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the sub items to a 'children' key of the array. Here is an example:

```
$list = array(
  'item1' => t('Item 1'),
  'item2' => array(
    'data' => t('Item 2'),
    'children' => array(
      t('Item 3'),
    ),
  ),
  'item4' => t('Item 4'),
);

return theme('item_list', array('items' =>  $list));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected! I posted a follow-up question: [How to render theme('item_list') as a collapsable menu?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226023/how-to-render-themeitem-list-as-a-collapsable-menu)